# A pythonic way to insert a space before capital letters

Tags: python, regex, text-files

I've got a file whose format I'm altering via a python script.  I have several camel cased strings in this file where I just want to insert a single space before the capital letter - so "WordWordWord" becomes "Word Word Word".

My limited regex experience just stalled out on me - can someone think of a decent regex to do this, or (better yet) is there a more pythonic way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could try:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "WordWordWord")
'Word Word Word'
```

Comment: re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "SorryIThinkYouMissedASpot")

Comment: As a small improvement, [[:upper:]] should be used instead of [A-Z].

Comment: @Tomalak, `[[:upper:]]` is not supported by Python. It is a [POSIX bracket expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Comment: For those like me, make sure you - import re

Answer (score 38):

If there are consecutive capitals, then Gregs result could
not be what you look for, since the \w consumes the caracter
in front of the captial letter to be replaced.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "WordWordWWWWWWWord")
'Word Word WW WW WW Word'
```

A look-behind would solve this:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=\w)([A-Z])", r" \1", "WordWordWWWWWWWord")
'Word Word W W W W W W Word'
```

Comment: Dan's answer is better and simpler :)

Comment: @hayalci: re.sub('([A-Z])', r' \1', 'Really?')

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at my answer on *[.NET - How can you split a “caps” delimited string into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155303/net-how-can-you-split-a-caps-delimited-string-into-an-array#155487)*

**Edit:** Maybe better to include it here.

```
re.sub(r'([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))', r'\1 ', text)
```

For example:

```
"SimpleHTTPServer" => ["Simple", "HTTP", "Server"]
```

Comment: Your answer is probably what Electrons_Ahoy really wants; however, based on the phrasing of their question, it's not.

Comment: but thank you for sharing this one, this is an awesome answer!

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps shorter:

```
>>> re.sub(r"\B([A-Z])", r" \1", "DoIThinkThisIsABetterAnswer?")
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, `\B` is "Not word boundary". So it's not inserting spaces where there's already a space.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you would be interested in one-liner implementation without using regexp:

```
''.join(' ' + char if char.isupper() else char.strip() for char in text).strip()
```

Comment: Elegant answer... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

With regexes you can do this:

```
re.sub('([A-Z])', r' \1', str)
```

Of course, that will only work for ASCII characters, if you want to do Unicode it's a whole new can of worms :-)

Comment: re.sub('([A-Z])', r' \1', "Do we want a space before the D's of this phrase?")

Comment: Ah, yes, good point.  Looks like your's and Leonhard's solutions handle this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have acronyms, you probably do not want spaces between them. This two-stage regex will keep acronyms intact (and also treat punctuation and other non-uppercase letters as something to add a space on):

```
re_outer = re.compile(r'([^A-Z ])([A-Z])')
re_inner = re.compile(r'(?<!^)([A-Z])([^A-Z])')
re_outer.sub(r'\1 \2', re_inner.sub(r' \1\2', 'DaveIsAFKRightNow!Cool'))
```

The output will be: `'Dave Is AFK Right Now! Cool'`

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the regex solution is the easiest, but I wouldn't say it's the most pythonic.

How about:

```
text = 'WordWordWord'
new_text = ''

for i, letter in enumerate(text):
    if i and letter.isupper():
        new_text += ' '

    new_text += letter
```

Comment: This has the same problem as Dan's - you'll get extra spaces before capitals even if they aren't needed.

Comment: True, i've edited it to add a flag...  I admit it's a little cumbersome, but may be easier to remember than regex.

Answer (score 1):

To the old thread - wanted to try an option for one of my requirements.  Of course the `re.sub()` is the cool solution, but also got a 1 liner if re module isn't (or shouldn't be) imported.

```py
st = 'ThisIsTextStringToSplitWithSpace'
print(''.join([' '+ s if s.isupper()  else s for s in st]).lstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regexes are the way to go here, but just to give a pure python version without (hopefully) any of the problems ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ has pointed out:

```
def splitCaps(s):
    result = []
    for ch, next in window(s+" ", 2):
        result.append(ch)
        if next.isupper() and not ch.isspace():
            result.append(' ')
    return ''.join(result)
```

window() is a utility function I use to operate on a sliding window of items, defined as:

```
import collections, itertools

def window(it, winsize, step=1):
    it=iter(it)  # Ensure we have an iterator
    l=collections.deque(itertools.islice(it, winsize))
    while 1:  # Continue till StopIteration gets raised.
        yield tuple(l)
        for i in range(step):
            l.append(it.next())
            l.popleft()
```