# A pythonic way to insert a space before capital letters but not insert space between an Abbreviation

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I've got a file whose format I'm altering via a python script. I have several camel cased strings in this file where I just want to insert a single space before the capital letter - so "WordWordWord" becomes "Word Word Word" but I also have some abbreviations as well, Like in the text "General Manager or VP".

I found an answer from David Underhill in this post:

[A pythonic way to insert a space before capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199059/a-pythonic-way-to-insert-a-space-before-capital-letters/46760056#46760056)

While this answer helps me to not insert spaces between abbreviations inside the text like "DaveIsAFKRightNow!Cool"

But it sure inserts a space between V and P in "VP".

I only have 25 experience points and i am unable to comment on the existing post, i am left with no other choice than to create another post for this similar sort of problem.

I am not that good at RegEx and not able to figure how to handle this situation.

I have tried this:

```
re_outer = re.compile(r'([^A-Z ])([A-Z])')
re_inner = re.compile(r'(?<!^)([A-Z])([^A-Z])')
re_outer.sub(r'\1 \2', re_inner.sub(r' \1\2', 'DaveIsAFKRightNow!Cool'))
```

It gives me 'Dave Is AFK Right Now! Cool'

My text sample is this:

```
General Manager or VP Torrance, CARequired education
```

I want the output as: `General Manager or VP Torrance, CA Required education`

The Output i am getting is: `General Manager or V P Torrance, CA Required education`

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/164602/david-underhill Could you please help me out with a minor improvement to your answer? 

TIA

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/jfgNAB

Comment: Perhaps using an alternation https://regex101.com/r/EQx7NJ/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may swap the replacements to first insert spaces before uppercase letters that are preceded with chars other than uppercase letters and spaces, and then append a space before words that start with 1+ uppercase letters that are followed with an uppercase and a lowercase letter:

```
import re
re_outer = re.compile(r'([^A-Z ])([A-Z])')
re_inner = re.compile(r'\b[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z])')
print(re_inner.sub(r'\g<0> ', re_outer.sub(r'\1 \2', 'DaveIsAFKRightNow!Cool')))
# => Dave Is AFK Right Now! Cool
print(re_inner.sub(r'\g<0> ', re_outer.sub(r'\1 \2', 'General Manager or VP Torrance, CARequired education'))) 
# => General Manager or VP Torrance, CA Required education
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jfgNAB)

The `\b[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z])` regex matches

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]+` - 1+ uppercase letters that are
- `(?=[A-Z][a-z])` - followed with an uppercase letter and a lowercase letter.

Note that `\g<0>` inserts the whole match in the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might use a single pattern with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
((?<=[^\W[A-Z])[A-Z]|(?<=\S)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))
```

In the replacement use a space followed by group 1:

```
 \1
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture group

  - `(?<=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

    - `[^\W[A-Z]` Match a word character except for A-Z
  - `)` Close positive lookahead
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=\S)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is
  - `[A-Z]` Match A-Z
  - `(?=[a-z])` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is a-z
- `)` Close capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EQx7NJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3ze81g)

For example

```
import re

strings = [
    "General Manager or VP Torrance, CARequired education",
    "WordWordWord",
    "DaveIsAFKRightNow!Cool"
]
pattern = re.compile(r'((?<=[^\W[A-Z])[A-Z]|(?<=\S)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))')

for str in strings:
    print(pattern.sub(r' \1', str))
```

Result

```
General Manager or VP Torrance, CA Required education
Word Word Word
Dave Is AFK Right Now! Cool
```