# Split a Pascal-case string into logical set of words

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to take a pascal-cased string like "CountOfWidgets" and convert it into something more user-friendly like "Count of Widgets" in C#. Multiple adjacent uppercase characters should be left intact. What is the most efficient way to do this?

**NOTE**: Duplicate of [.NET - How can you split a "caps" delimited string into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155303/net-how-can-you-split-a-caps-delimited-string-into-an-array)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question because the answer linked to does not cater for "Multiple adjacent uppercase character should be left intact"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't know about efficient but at least it's terse:

```
Regex r = new Regex("([A-Z]+[a-z]+)");
string result = r.Replace("CountOfWidgets", m => (m.Value.Length > 3 ? m.Value : m.Value.ToLower()) + " ");
```

Comment: This leaves a space at the end of "FormatRange" -> "FormatRange " - so a trim would be useful and checking for Length of 3 is a unreliable way of ensuring "multiple adjacent uppercase should be left intact". This just hopes that anything less than 3 characters should be left. So "PubID" goes to "publ ID" which is not right