# Bind enum with ObjectDataProvider

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, enums, objectdataprovider

I have an enum that bind to a `ComboBox` in my view.

```
public enum MyItems
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    Item1,

    [Browsable(true)]
    Item2,

    [Browsable(false)]
    Item3,

    [Browsable(true)]
    Item4,
}
```

In view I use `ObjectDataProvider`

```
 <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="eMyItems" MethodName="GetValues"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="Enums:MyItems"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>:
```

My ComboBox look like this:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource eMyItems}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Item}"/>
```

The problem is that I see **all the Enum** even the ones that above them have  `[Browsable(false)]`.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Data binding: How to data bind an enum to combo box using XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306743/wpf-data-binding-how-to-data-bind-an-enum-to-combo-box-using-xaml)

Comment: XAML has no concept of skipping over enums that are marked [Browsable(false)].  The BrowsableAttribute is for interactive Properties windows at design time, nothing more.  The other linked SO question merely repurposes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the answers in this related question looks like it might be of help to you:

[WPF Data binding: How to data bind an enum to combo box using XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306743/wpf-data-binding-how-to-data-bind-an-enum-to-combo-box-using-xaml)

Comment: I saw this answer, I do not know where to use EnumerationManager. I wonder if there is any attr that sat to ObjectDataProvider to refer to browsable.

Comment: The only change you need to make to your code is the inclusion of EnumerationManager in whichever namespace seems appropriate. And to change the ObjectType in your ObjectDataProvider definition to namespace:EnumerationManager. I don't think there is anyway to do what you want without the helper class to search for the Browsable attribute.