# C# WPF - ComboBox DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to understand the concept of DataBinding a combobox with an object.

I have the following class:

```
public class employmentApplication
{
  private byte appType = 0; // 1 = normal; 2 = expedited

  public byte AppType
  {
    get { return appType ; }
    set
    {
      appType = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged("AppType");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
  {
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
      this.PropertyChanged(
      this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
  }
}
```

My xaml for the combobox is

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="Normal" />
  <ComboBoxItem Content="Expedited" />
</ComboBox>
```

I am not sure where to begin to bind my combobox to the AppType since it has to convert it from a string ("Normal", "Expedited") to a byte (0, 1) and back between the object and the combobox.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use ValueConverter. It's more flexable solution than using **Tag** values and it's looks nice because you are separating conversion logic in its own class. Also I noticed that in your data class you declared **PropertyChanged** event but not implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface so you can't have two way binding in this case. Full example:

**Your data class (with my fixes)**

```
public class EmploymentApplication : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private byte appType = 0; // 1 = normal; 2 = expedited

    public byte AppType
    {
        get { return appType; }
        set
        {
            appType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AppType");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    } 
}
```

**Value converter**

```
public class AppTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var b = (byte)value;
        if (b == 1) return "Normal";
        if (b == 2) return "Expedited";
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var strValue = (string) value;
        byte result = 0;
        if (strValue.Equals("Normal", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            result = 1;
        }
        else if (strValue.Equals("Expedited", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            result = 2;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new EmploymentApplication();
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfConvertion.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfConvertion"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AppTypeConverter x:Key="Converter"></local:AppTypeConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="20" SelectedValue="{Binding AppType, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" SelectedValuePath="Content">
        <ComboBoxItem>Normal</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Expedited</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Pay attention on this line: **xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfConvertion"**. You must set your own namespace here instead of my WpfConvertion.

Comment: This does what I want, however, I am looking for a way to modify the value converter to be more dynamic. This is just an example of what I am trying to do. I will have other combo boxes with only two values (0,1) but different display text.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this several ways, however here is a simple solution todo what you have asked. Note, your `DataContext` will need to be set to your instance of the class you want to represent.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding AppType, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="Tag">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Normal" Tag="0"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Expedited" Tag="1"/>
</ComboBox>
```

`SelectedValue` is binded to your property, and [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the property of `ComboBoxItem` (in this case) that will represent the selected value.

This is a very simple solution, and you may need to alter it for your needs. Additionally, I would consider using an `Enum` to represent this data. It will make it a little easier to understand what you are trying todo in code.

**Edit**

---

Here is an example of using an `enum` with the above example. I'm going to use your already existing code as a base.

Create an enum (preferably in a new file).

```
public enum AppType
{
    Normal,
    Expedited
}
```

Now modify your property to use the enum

```
public AppType AppType
{
    get
    {
        return appType;
    }
    set
    {
        if( Equals( appType, value ) ) return;
        appType = value;

        OnPropertyChanged( "AppType" );
    }
}
```

Now you can use my above example, but with an enum:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding AppType, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="Tag">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Normal" Tag="{x:Static local:AppType.Normal}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Expedited" Tag="{x:Static local:AppType.Expedited"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The following is nice for having a little more control over what is displayed in the `ComboBox`. However you can also have it display every `enum` value, which is nice because if you add `enum` values in the future, they will automatically show up in the `ComboBox`. [See this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306743/wpf-data-binding-how-to-data-bind-an-enum-to-combo-box-using-xaml) for a way of doing that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by using an Enum? I want to do this correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this  the simplest could be to add a bind to your AppType with SelectedIndex property   of your ComboBox 
Note that you should add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to let your binding work

and in code behind do the following

```
namespace WpfApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        employmentApplication  emp = new employmentApplication();  

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = emp;  
        }
    }
    public class employmentApplication:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private byte appType = 0; // 1 = normal; 2 = expedited

        public byte AppType
        {
            get { return appType; }
            set
            {
                appType = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("AppType");
            }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;          

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work fine, however I feel it's not very robust, and you are forcing yourself to add additional properties to support a single control.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is, if yout Normal value is 0 and your Expedited value is 1, use SelectedIndex to bind to.

`<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding AppType}" >`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a converter, or tags, as the other answers have shown. But you could also define your item-source as a class rather than rely on hand-waving to link integers to strings.
So your item source items could be a class like this:

```
public class AppType
{
    public string Name;
    public byte Type;
}
```

You can then use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath binding on your combobox to define what changes in your datacontext, and what property is used in the lookup list.

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemSource = {Binding ListOfAppTypes}
    SelectedValue="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Name">
</ComboBox>
```

You could also define a Template for your Combobox where you gain more control over how the lookup list of items is displayed.