# Regex for a case change

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get a string to have an underscore '_' everywhere on a case changes in a string to make it more clear to the user. For example if we have a String 'personal IDnumber', I want to make it to 'personal_ID_number'. This is in C#.

Thank you, I appreciate any help, suggestions.

-Sid

Comment: In your case you also replaced a white space with an underscore. Is this also what you are looking for? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: white space is not an issue, I am only trying to get an underscore on every case change, I tried a split on every uppercase letter, that didn't work, now i am trying to check every char for its case and comparing its case with case of every character before and  after that. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET - How can you split a "caps" delimited string into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155303/net-how-can-you-split-a-caps-delimited-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Replace on a case change**
You are looking for this (I removed the space before ID, assuming it a typo)

```
(?:(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]))|(?:(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z]))
```

It will transform `personalIDnumber` into `personal_ID_number`

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uaii)

the Lookbehind (`(?<=[a-z])`) and lookahead (`(?=[A-Z])`) construction is matching the empty string between a lower case and a uppercase letter (or the other way round in the second part after the pipe `|`) and replace this with a underscore.

**Replace on a case change with optional whitespace**
If you want to include whitespace in the replace, just include it between the lookarounds

```
(?:(?<=[a-z])\s*(?=[A-Z]))|(?:(?<=[A-Z])\s*(?=[a-z]))
```

It will transform `personal IDnumber` into `personal_ID_number`

See this [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uail)

**Replace on a case change, but each word starts with an uppercase**
If you say every word starts with an uppercase letter, then you can do this

```
(?:(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]))|(?:(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z]))
```

This will make from

> PersonalIDNumber
>   JustAnotherTest
>   OtherWordWithID
>   SomeMORETest

this

> Personal_ID_Number
>   Just_Another_Test
>   Other_Word_With_ID
>   Some_MORE_Test

See this [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uajd)

Comment: Thank you stema, Ill try it and let you know.

Comment: Sorry, this works but I have another another case which fails if I have 'personelIDNumber', I want to get 'personal_ID_Number'. right now it gives personal_IDN_umber

Comment: How should I distinguish if the last uppercase belongs to last word or if it is the first of the next one? I think there is no way, because the pattern has no idea of the meaning of the word. Or you say every word starts with an uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Non-regex solution (just in case)

```
    string str = "personalIDnumber";
    var result =
        Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length - 1)
            .Where(i => char.IsUpper(str[i]) != char.IsUpper(str[i + 1]))
            .ToList();

    string resultString = result.Aggregate(str, (current, i) => current.Insert(i + 1 + result.IndexOf(i), "_"));
```

the `result` stores a list of locations where an `_` has to be inserted and the `Aggregate()` function inserts it.

Comment: I got it working, I used "(?x)( [A-Z][a-z,0-9]+ | [A-Z]+(?![a-z]))" with _$1, and I got output with _ in from if the string started with a Capital letter, I stripped off the first underscore form string. Thanks Everyone.